# Replacement for WinRes

Tags: .net, localization

We have a localization process for a .NET project that relies on Winres to allow non-programmers to adjust control placement and text.

But Winres is sometimes unable to show us the UI, or parts of it.  The explanations it provides are unclear and we (obviously) can't get inside it and debug it.

Any alternatives out there?